# Libgdx ( Input) Keypress seems to skip something

Tags: java, input, keyboard, libgdx

Hello once again oh mighty people of the internet! I have decided to go with libGDX for creating a simple memory game to become better at java. I have solved, and tested a lot of things already by myself, but i have come across a problem that i just. can't. figure. out.

I have created a complete cluster of if statements to create a menu that has buttons that can be selected by the arrow keys (I couldn't figure out how to make them clickable buttons :P) and it seems to work fine except that it skips one of the buttons which is my high scores button. I will only post the levelSelection Screen class, since that's the one i'm sure the problem is in.

The levelSelection Screen class:

```
package com.me.mygdxgame;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;


public class levelSelection implements Screen {
           private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
           private Texture playB;
           private Texture exitB;
           private Texture hScoreB;
           private Texture backGround;
           MyGdxGame game;
           private boolean playButton;
           private boolean quitButton;
           private boolean highScoresButton;
           BitmapFont  font;


    public levelSelection(MyGdxGame game) {
        this.game = game;


    }



    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor( 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f );
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 

        spriteBatch.begin();
        spriteBatch.draw(backGround, 0, 0);
        spriteBatch.draw(playB, 250, 450);
        spriteBatch.draw(exitB, 250, 350);
        spriteBatch.draw(hScoreB, 250, 400);
        spriteBatch.end();

        //Start Navigation Between menu buttons

            if(playButton == true && quitButton == false && highScoresButton == false && Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN)){
                playButton = false;
                quitButton = false;
                highScoresButton = true;
                System.out.println("HighScores button is selected");

            }
            if(highScoresButton == true && playButton == false && quitButton == false && Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN)){
               highScoresButton = false;
               playButton = false;
               quitButton = true;
               System.out.println("quit button is selected");

    }
            if(quitButton == true && playButton == false && highScoresButton == false && Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP)){
                quitButton = false;
                playButton = false;
                highScoresButton = true;
                System.out.println("HighScores button is selected");
            }
             if(highScoresButton == true && quitButton == false && playButton == false && Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP)){
                 quitButton = false;
                 highScoresButton = false;
                 playButton = true;
                 System.out.println("Play button is selected");
             }

             //end navigation between menu buttons

                 if(playButton == true && Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.ENTER)){
                     game.setScreen(game.GameScreen);
                 }
                 if(quitButton == true && Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.ENTER)){
                     game.dispose();
                 }

                 //Draw text according to selected button
                if(highScoresButton == true){
                    spriteBatch.begin();
                    font.draw(spriteBatch, "High Score Button is Selected!", 15, 15);
                    spriteBatch.end();
                }
                if(quitButton == true){
                    spriteBatch.begin();
                    font.draw(spriteBatch, "Quit Button is Selected!", 15, 15);
                    spriteBatch.end();
                }
                if(playButton == true){
                    spriteBatch.begin();
                    font.draw(spriteBatch, "Play Button is Selected!", 15, 15);
                    spriteBatch.end();
                }
            }
```

I believe the problem is that the game is running at high speeds, and for some reason when i hit the button (up or down) it does it more than once.

Comment: you should really use scene2d! It is much easier and with this (http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2d) tutorial i think you understand it soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem:

It usually runs at approximately 60 fps. So it'd obviously be difficult to let it happen only once.

---

### Solution:

For one keystroke, you could allow only one transition.

To achieve this,

1. Store last pressed key.
2. If the currently pressed key is same as the stored key, do nothing.
3. Update it's value after each button focus transition.
4. Set it's value to null at if that key isn't pressed any more (one more if condition :D )

---

**Notes:**

1. Don't use boolean for each button. It makes conditions very verbose. In stead, use an integer like `int selectedButtonIndex = 0;` and update it's value everytime.
2. This is not a standard way to implement a menu in libgdx. You are trying to implement everything from scratch. But the framework already provides many higher level functionalities when it comes to ui. Try searching **scene2d ui** on the internet. You'd find many resources. (You will get clickable buttons there. :D )

Good luck.

Comment: +1 for this answer. Just a question: Isn't there a method in libgdx to disable keyevents to be fired more then once. Something like `Keyboard.enableRepeatableEvents(false);`. As much as i know i used this for my first game, but i can't look at source code right now...

Comment: @Springrbua : Thanks for reminding about it. Apparently same thing has already been implemented by libgdx itself. :D

Comment: @TanmayPatil so i am not wrong? xD I tryed to google it but could not find it anymore... However i allready implemented it xD

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/detail?id=1064 .. I guess it has been removed now.